# Why Integrating Spring Cloud application with the AWS Parameter Store return no property from param store?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

**Intent** : I am working on a POC which intends to use AWS Parameter store as a property store.This would store the confidential application properties in AWS SSM's Parameter store.I am using Java 8 with spring boot/cloud version 2.

**Resource** : I followed [this ref guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_parameter_store) from spring docs
and

also a comprehensive article [Integrating the AWS Parameter Store with Spring Cloud](https://blog.trifork.com/2018/07/20/integrating-the-aws-parameter-store-with-spring-cloud/) .Hence was trying to utilize

> spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config.jar

and hence added required dependency in the build file.

**Expected output :**

[image]

**Actual output** :

[image]

Here is **snapshot from AWS console** I am trying to access below shown parameters from AWS parameter store

[image]

Below are my spring property files:

**application.yml**

[image]

**bootstrap.yml**

[image]

I am using maven with below dependencies in **POM.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Am I missing something here?? Please let me know if someone has already faced and resolved this issue.

I am able to put and get parameter from command line,its just not able to get this java lib working.

GitHub repo of the sample I am trying -

[GitHub repo link](https://github.com/MaheshLoya/springcloud-aws-paramstore-integration-sample/tree/master)

Comment: the screen of the parameter store is it from the same region as ap-south-1?

Comment: @slimane Yes.. from the same region.. ap-south-1,infact I am using only tht region in Dev env of my aws instance

Comment: what do you mean by  I am using only tht region in Dev env of my aws instance

Comment: @slimane I have environment specific aws accounts,i.e different for prod and dev.In dev specific account all the proof of concepts are done in ap-south-1 region only.

I can retrieve using CLI from same machine,where I am running this app, and it defaults to ap-south-1.

Comment: maybe the region.auto=true property  will override the static value, can you verify it?

Comment: @slimane , I hv verified it.That doesnt make any difference..setting it to auto, makes it fetch it from instance meta data,which again points to ap-south-1

Comment: so why do you have "application" parameters exposed in "my-service" app?do you have a link to your sample app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186227/discussion-between-mahesh-loya-and-slimane).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked your app, it didn't work as expected for me as I had ~.aws/config file which leads to misconfiguration of AWS credentials(cause by `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`, read more [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-aws.adoc#simple-credentials-configuration) ), so I removed it, and I tried again but it fails saying that spring can't find aws region in the env, so apparently those specified in application.yml won't be used until spring loads properties from AWS parameter store.

**How I made it work**

I added:

```
        System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId","My_Key");
        System.setProperty("aws.secretKey","Secret");
        System.setProperty("aws.region","us-east-1");//same region where all your params exist
```

before `SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);` and then it worked.

**when changing the `aws.region` to another one where there are no params value defined I got the exact same result as yours (empty values).**

**make sure there isn't any aws config on your machine or EC2 instance that will override those provided in your app.**

Comment: yes you are right.. I had issue with .aws/config file